# Undefined local variable or method `link' for #<#<Class:0x007ffbfb1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

An error occurs on -  `link.each do |l|`

```
#links.tab-pane.fade.in{class: "#{'active' if params[:tab] == 'Links'}" }
  %h1 Links
  .table-responsive
    %table.datatable.display.table.table-bordered.table-hover.align-left{:cellspacing => "0", :width => "100%"}
      %thead
        %tr
          %th Name
          %th URL
          %th Active
          %th Edit
      %tbody
        -link.each do |l|
          %tr
            %td=link_to l.id, edit_managers_account_link_path(account, l)
            %td=l.name
            %td=l.url
            / %td=u.active ? 'YES' : 'NO' 
            %td=link_to (image_tag ("hand_icon1.png")), edit_managers_account_link_path(account, l) 
      %tfoot
        %tr
        %td{colspan: '5'}=link_to 'Add User', new_managers_account_link_path(account)
```

Comment: how should it be formatted?

Comment: Seems Trevor Hickey already did this.

Comment: well, can be better formatted with correct 2ws indentation

Answer (score 1):

`link` is a local variable which isnst setted somewhere before.

either you need to set `@links` from the controller (eg `@links = Manager.find(params[:id]).links`) or you need to get correct data inside your template something like

```
-@manager.link.each do |link|
-Link.all.each do |link|
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `link` defined anywhere.

If you've defined it in your controller, you should use an instance variable not a local variable (e.g. `@link` not `link`) because local variables are not shared with the view.